# How do I refresh when touch drag is finished on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, refresh

I have a problem with the `refresh` part. Currently, the function to `refresh` is OK.

But I want to refresh when the user has finished touching the iphone.

```swift
var refController:UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    refController.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 40.0, width: refController.bounds.size.width, height: refController.bounds.size.height)
    refController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.webviewRefresh(refresh:)), for: .valueChanged)
    refController.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "refreshing")
    WKWebView.scrollView.addSubview(refController)
    if contentController.userScripts.count > 0 {
        contentController.removeAllUserScripts()
    }
...
}
@objc func webviewRefresh(refresh:UIRefreshControl){
    refController.endRefreshing()
    WKWebView.reload()
}
```

Currently, Even if user haven't finished touch at this time, when the screen is lowered to a certain height, a refresh is performed on the screen.

But I want to run a refresh when the user has finished touching the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call refresh method in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` delegate method of `UIScrollViewDelegate`. So import `UIScrollViewDelegate` in your `ViewController` Like,

```
extension YourViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if self.refController.isRefreshing {
            self.webviewRefresh()
        }
    }
}
```

Then your `webviewRefresh` will be,

```
    @objc func webviewRefresh(){
        refController.endRefreshing()
        WKWebView.reload()
    }
```

And your`viewDidLoad` will be,

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        refController.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 40.0, width: refController.bounds.size.width, height: refController.bounds.size.height)
        refController.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "refreshing")
        WKWebView.scrollView.addSubview(refController)
        WKWebView.scrollView.delegate = self
        if contentController.userScripts.count > 0 {
            contentController.removeAllUserScripts()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use crrefresh library for doing this thing

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Please use the library to create an example for my environment.